# Is there a way to set variable in UPDATE statement in PostgreSQL (plpgsql)?

Tags: postgresql

Something like this:

```
DECLARE
c INTEGER;
UPDATE table SET col = (c := col + 1) WHERE id = 1;
```

This is wrong:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":="
```

how to do it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the update only affects one row:

```
DECLARE
c INTEGER;
UPDATE table SET col = col + 1 WHERE id = 1
  RETURNING col INTO c;
```

[Reference](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW).